# VBA Word "insertsymbol" failure with high value unicode for maths symbols

Tags: vba, unicode, runtime-error, ms-word

In MS Word, you can add any Unicode by its number. For instance &H1D539 is for a script capital B. You just have to enter 1D539 and then press alt-X and you get the nice script capital B.

You can also do it with selection.InsertSymbol in word VBA : 
`Selection.InsertSymbol CharacterNumber:=171, Unicode:=True`

Reference documentation says that CharacterNumber is a long integer.

But when I use InsertSymbol with &H1D539, I get a "error &H800a141c : number must be between -32768 and 32767".

It is in contradiction with CharacterNumber being a long integer and that you can use such "high" Unicode numbers when by hand.

Using maths symbols, the whole table I use is above 32768 ...

P.S. I tried to record a macro, and the alt-C is done through `Selection.ToggleCharacterCode` ; I worked out through this method but I would prefer something more straightforward !

Comment: what kind of symbol you are trying to insert? in which font I could find it?

Comment: You need to break it up into surrogate pairs, then use InsertAfter to add them.

Comment: @KazJaw : I needed mathematical symbols and the MS Word built-in interface is so time-consuming that I preferred to use a macro to enter directly the Unicode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code should convert a Unicode codepoint into a Visual Basic string, of either one character, or a surrogate pair, as necessary:

```
Function StringFromCodepoint(ByVal CodePoint As Long) As String
    If CodePoint <= &HFFFF& Then
        StringFromCodepoint = ChrW(CodePoint)
        Exit Function
    ElseIf CodePoint > &H10FFFF& Or CodePoint <= 0 Then
        Err.Raise 5, "Invalid Codepoint: " & Str(CodePoint)
        Exit Function
    Else
        CodePoint = CodePoint - &H10000&
        Dim SurrogateLow As Long
        Dim SurrogateHigh As Long
        SurrogateLow = CodePoint And &H3FF&
        SurrogateHigh = (CodePoint - SurrogateLow) / &H400&
        StringFromCodepoint = ChrW(SurrogateHigh Or &HD800&) + ChrW(SurrogateLow Or &HDC00&)
        Exit Function
    End If
End Function
```

You can then use something like this:

```
Selection.InsertAfter StringFromCodepoint(&h1D539&)
```

Comment: Great ! Your piece of code worked just fine !
For those who wonder like I did the basis of the magic, in short :

Comment: surrogate characters is a technique that uses 2 16-bit characters to code up to &H110000 characters outside the main plane of characters. The two surrogate characters are two bunches of 1024 characters coded between &HD800 and &HDBFF and between &HC00 and &HDFFF. Therefore only CodePoints less than &H110000 are allowed, and the 2 characters to code a valid CodePoint are computed as Ben did.

Thanks again Ben for your expertise, you open a completely new world for me ! (aside the fact that you gave a ready-made solution !!)

Comment: Jsut a comment for those that would like to use the piece of code : there is a problem with the comparision  `CodePoint <= &HFFFF` since &HFFFF is coerced as a signed hexa to -1 ; `CodePoint <= 65535` works fine ; `CodePoint > &H10FFFF` can be replaced by `CodePoint > 1114111`

Comment: Or even simpler, by adding "&" at the end of the hexadecimal constant to signify an unsigned long integer

Comment: @user1771398, thanks for catching that, fixed. Technically it is still signed (as VB doesn't do unsigned) but it doesn't matter in that range.

Comment: @user1771398, fixed again;.

Comment: @Ben thanks - very helpful routine!  Would you by any chance be willing to license it CC-BY, MIT, or some other non-copyleft license?  (I've licensed all my contributions CC-BY, so I'm not asking for anything I'm not willing to do myself :) )  Thank you for considering this request!

Answer (score 1):

Related problem is a get inserted symbol's code.
Solution is to use dialog capabilities in context of selected symbol:

http://word.mvps.org/faqs/macrosvba/FindReplaceSymbols.htm

```
Sub GetCharNoAndFont()

    With Dialogs(wdDialogInsertSymbol)
        Debug.Print "Font: " & .Font
        Debug.Print "Char number " & .CharNum
    End With

End Sub
```